# How to make a Response.Write(...); in my Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Controller with the following method:

```
public void ExportList()
{
    var out = GenExport();

    CsvExport<LiveViewListe> csv = new CsvExport<LiveViewListe>(out);
    Response.Write(csv.Export());
}
```

this should generate a csv file which the user can download.

I call this method via a jQuery request in my view:

```
$.getJSON('../Controller2/ExportList', function (data) {
    //...
});
```

the problem is, that I don't get any download and I don't know why. The method is called but without a download.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your controller methods need to always return an `ActionResult`. So the method should look more like

```
public ActionResult ExportList()
{
    var export = GenExport();

    CsvExport<LiveViewListe> csv = new CsvExport<LiveViewListe>(export);
    return new CsvResult(csv);
}
```

Where `CsvResult` is a class inheriting from `ActionResult` and doing the necessary to prompt the user for download of your Csv results.

For example, if you really need to `Response.Write` this could be:

```
public class CsvResult : ActionResult
{
    private CsvExport<LiveViewListe> data;
    public CsvResult (CsvExport<LiveViewListe> data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file.csv"));

        if (data!= null)
        {
            response.Write(data.Export());
        }
    }
}
```

You could also think about making this more generic, if your `CsvExport` class has the `Export` method:

```
public class CsvResult<T> : ActionResult
{

    private CsvExport<T> data;
    public CsvResult (CsvExport<T> data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    .... same ExecuteResult code
}
```

Now it supports any of your csv downloads, not just `LiveViewListe`.

Comment: `FileResult` must be provided with the location of, or file content, to write to the response stream. The OP appeared to have their own mechanism (`.Export()`) of getting the data in Csv format. This code just did the bare necessary to get the data into the response stream - it also demonstrates a little of the internals of Mvc which can be customised.

Comment: My mistake, I meant [`Controller.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470835(v=vs.98).aspx).

Comment: @ta.speot.is - Thats just a wrapper method around `FileContentResult` and has the same problem as described above - needs a `byte[]` to be passed as the data and im not sure the user has that. If OP's `CsvExport.Export` method returns `byte[]` then happy day - use `FileContentResult` as it does much the same as my code above.

Comment: What's the consequence of calling `$.getJSON` on something that returns something that's not JSON?

Comment: I changes the JSON request to a normal link to the new controller method, and now its working!